# Angular 2 error on starting server: Config did not export an object

Tags: angular, webpack

I just recently updated my Angular 2 project to the lastest versions. I am using webpack

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "loyalty-one-lois",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Loyalty One LOIS",
  "keywords": [
    "Loyalty One",
    "LOIS",
    "BRMS"
  ],
  "author": "Loyalty One",
  "homepage": "https://www.loyalty.com/",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.4",
    "@angular2-material/core": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.13",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@angularclass/request-idle-callback": "^1.0.7",
    "@angularclass/webpack-toolkit": "^1.3.3",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "mydatepicker": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^1.4.8",
    "ng2-my-datepicker": "^0.1.1",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "primeng": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/protractor": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0 ",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "^5.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.8.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.6",
    "string-replace-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.5",
    "typescript": "2.1.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "2.4.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

I have deleted node_modules, run npm cache clean and rerun npm install. When I try to start the server using npm start

```
C:\louis-ui\lois-ui-ng2>npm start

> loyalty-one-lois@1.0.0 start C:\louis-ui\lois-ui-ng2
> npm run server:dev


> loyalty-one-lois@1.0.0 server:dev C:\louis-ui\lois-ui-ng2
> webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/

Config did not export an object.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run
" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! loyalty-one-lois@1.0.0 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --wa
tch --content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the loyalty-one-lois@1.0.0 server:dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --pro
gress --profile --watch --content-base src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the loyalty-one-lois package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs loyalty-one-lois
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls loyalty-one-lois
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\louis-ui\lois-ui-ng2\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "sta
rt"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! loyalty-one-lois@1.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the loyalty-one-lois@1.0.0 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the loyalty-one-lois package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run server:dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs loyalty-one-lois
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls loyalty-one-lois
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\louis-ui\lois-ui-ng2\npm-debug.log
```

My webpack.config.js file is as follows

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

// Look in ./config folder for webpack.dev.js
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod')({env: 'production'});
    break;
  case 'test':
  case 'testing':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.test')({env: 'test'});
    break;
  case 'dev':
  case 'development':
  default:

    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')({env: 'development'});
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.